# How to set the range of y-axis for a seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, boxplot

From the [official seaborn documentation](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html), I learned that you can create a boxplot as below:

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image: Seaborn Boxplot Example]

My question is: how do I limit the range of y-axis of this plot? For example, I want the y-axis to be within [10, 40]. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It is standard `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ylim(10, 40)
```

Or simpler, as mwaskom comments below:

```
ax.set(ylim=(10, 40))
```

[image]