# How do I change x and y axis limits in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, axis

below are my values for x and y coordinates

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

x = np.random.randint(1,10,10)
y = np.random.randint(-100,10,10)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]

how do I change max and min values for x and y coordinates for instance

[image]

if I want to change X-Axis left to -5 and right to 10
likewise Y-Axis Bottom to -100 and top -20

The resulting figure

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the range of y-axis for a seaborn boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227473/how-to-set-the-range-of-y-axis-for-a-seaborn-boxplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this before plt.scattar

```
plt.xlim([-5, 10])
plt.ylim([-100, -20])
```

Sincerely yours,