# Using statannot with split violin plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I'm plotting some data as split violin and using `statannot` library to do T-test. I managed to get the plot and the annotation but I would like to **tune the horizontal offset** of the annotation. I checked the `statannot` example on [Github](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot/blob/master/example/example.ipynb), there seems to be options to set up y-offsets but not x.

My code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statannot
from statannot import add_stat_annotation

l1 = [272.504,202.512,193.069,167.855,154.232,152.334,151.609,148.53,146.403,145.133,144.645,143.988,139.266,138.655,133.887,133.661,133.434,133.17,131.556,131.256,130.978,129.105,128.842,126.593,126.333,124.542,123.76,123.492,123.22,121.734,120.375,119.656,119.108,118.642,118.401,118.309,116.836,116.416,115.601,114.028,113.992,113.288,113.144,112.626,112.616,112.496,111.561,110.76,110.111,110.092,109.331,109.135,109.012,108.903,108.552,106.474,106.42,106.019,105.885,105.525,105.439,105.366,104.982,104.805,104.744,104.664,104.335,104.184,103.707,103.457,103.323,103.249,103.098,102.37,102.315,102.016,101.378,99.8643,99.5172,99.2789,99.2084,99.0091,97.7338,97.6874,97.6814,97.4388,96.432,96.2432,96.0918,96.0247,95.839,95.297,95.1323,94.2848,93.2593,93.2341,93.0388,92.3403,91.8436,91.8328,91.6193,91.3894,91.222,90.8495,90.734,90.7058,90.6775,90.5114,90.1493,90.0493,89.7854,89.6923,89.0814,89.0667,88.995,88.9301,88.7436,88.3927,88.3131,88.0119,87.4159,87.0414,86.9434,86.8593,86.7524,86.7398,86.2706,86.176,86.0691,85.9919,85.7879,85.6841,85.6708,85.3463,84.1721,84.066,83.7766,83.1467,83.0892,82.9535,82.816,82.5275,82.4752,82.471,82.4688,82.4646,81.9346,81.5371,81.3621,81.3368,80.9333,80.7021,80.6517,80.5567,80.1604,79.892,79.586,79.5603,79.4095,79.3454,79.2852,79.2086,79.0203,78.8051,78.706,78.6477,78.3607,78.0428,77.8758,77.5691,77.5387,77.5311,77.5263,77.3324,77.29,77.2234,77.0692,77.0666,77.0413,76.7028,76.5951,76.4135,76.392,76.3454,76.0672,75.6534,75.5475,75.2686,75.0235,74.9092,74.4248,74.2518,74.2257,74.0593,73.9968,73.9246,73.8414,73.8408,73.7763,73.4484,73.2291,73.145,73.0303,72.9797,72.9751,72.9024,72.826,72.6676,72.4249,72.4102,72.0856,71.9704,71.9172,71.7447,71.7206,71.5958,71.439,71.4298,71.2355,71.2251,71.0718,71.053,70.5732,70.4904,70.1866,69.8816,69.4722,69.4509,69.3045,69.2798,69.1982,69.1069,69.0067,68.6909,68.5816,68.4733,68.4249,68.024,68.0039,67.9734,67.7469,67.7361,67.713,67.6114,67.6018,67.4642,67.2782,67.0869,67.0519,66.8222,66.7673,66.6673,66.2306,66.1987,66.1889,66.0974,65.9233,65.8449,65.6032,65.3384,65.0957,65.0477,64.8658,64.7849,64.7369,64.7189,64.6764,64.6755,64.6455,64.4755,64.306,64.246,64.2147,64.0402,64.0325,63.8272,63.8245,63.6099,63.3386,63.2451,63.0935,63.0666,62.5662,62.4672,62.4578,62.4012,62.2842,62.2709,62.1582,61.9314,61.904,61.827,61.8042,61.7518,61.6945,61.6762,61.6359,61.5333,61.4807,61.304,61.1901,61.1656,61.1317,61.1297,60.9643,60.8862,60.6479,60.5511,60.5056,60.4721,60.4157,60.3676,60.1445,60.091,60.0761,60.0467,60.0336,59.9166,59.8809,59.8731,59.6334,59.5349,59.4131,59.3963,59.3804,59.361,59.3408,59.3174,59.2815,59.199,59.1076,58.8374,58.8146,58.8089,58.7414,58.5541,58.4368,58.2797,58.2499,58.1815,58.1174,58.1069,58.105,58.0428,57.9885,57.8912,57.8868,57.8822,57.676,57.6351,57.4839,57.4002,57.2343,57.1967,57.1731,57.0824,57.0567,56.8848,56.7218,56.4508,56.3671,56.3229,56.3205,56.1875,56.1257,56.0954,55.9887,55.8555,55.8546,55.809,55.7402,55.6578,55.5996,55.5602,55.5339,55.4469,55.3462,55.3444,55.3205,55.3117,55.2178,55.1261,55.0886,55.0576,54.9589,54.81,54.7532,54.7457,54.7033,54.5629,54.4999,54.3627,54.3135,54.311,54.2713,54.1049,54.0707,53.9745,53.77,53.5395,53.5006,53.3687,53.3117,53.2583,53.2529,53.2011,53.177,52.9779,52.909,52.905,52.6222,52.6088,52.5059,52.4902,52.4878,52.3373,52.3323,52.3029,52.3012,52.234,52.0334,51.9882,51.9661,51.9633,51.9121,51.8698,51.8114,51.788,51.6296,51.6248,51.4913,51.4739,51.3667,51.2958,51.294,51.2281,51.1854,51.1286,51.1162,51.0855,50.8662,50.5744,50.5062,50.4847,50.4691,50.4474,50.4179,50.2679,50.2074,50.1622,50.1334,49.7874,49.48,49.4539,49.4231,49.272,49.2575,49.1364,49.092,49.0221,48.8856,48.8175,48.7647,48.6915,48.647,48.6371,48.5609,48.5368,48.4042,48.234,48.1098,48.0656,47.9973,47.8853,47.7601,47.2543,47.2029,47.1206,47.1194,47.0535,46.9547,46.8645,46.8117,46.6366,46.3982,46.2792,46.2024,46.0142,45.8344,45.8233,45.8128,45.7977,45.7417,45.5822,45.5592,45.4089,45.3844,45.3696,45.136,45.0556,45.0016,45.0011,44.7754,44.6891,44.6553,44.6383,44.507,44.1616,44.1418,44.0245,43.9803,43.9753,43.968,43.8356,43.8177,43.6451,43.5594,43.3305,43.2629,43.2173,43.186,42.9444,42.8459,42.8095,42.7937,42.6379,42.5311,42.5082,42.4254,42.2728,42.1527,42.0969,42.0669,41.9709,41.9636,41.9144,41.9029,41.8869,41.8605,41.716,41.4758,41.4287,41.0717,41.0059,41.0017,40.9169,40.8871,40.7063,40.6942,40.6885,40.5788,40.5018,40.3402,40.3285,40.3031,40.2406,40.1971,40.167,40.1385,40.0427,39.8397,39.699,39.6931,39.6284,39.2814,39.2729,39.263,39.1405,39.1393,39.1139,39.0489,38.9667,38.8357,38.6099,38.4053,38.009,37.9577,37.8777,37.3667,37.1155,37.0287,36.9916,36.5744,36.2806,36.1317,36.0718,36.0612,36.039,35.9404,35.8914,35.8179,35.738,35.6264,35.5055,35.4206,35.4184,35.3975,35.3173,35.2659,35.1784,35.0709,34.8165,34.7544,34.7423,34.6369,34.6334,34.3476,34.3354,34.2578,34.1394,33.9828,33.9191,33.6455,33.6272,33.598,33.5212,33.3422,33.2855,33.2689,32.9122,32.8871,32.8818,32.4971,32.3061,32.2169,32.1022,31.9352,31.6088,31.5756,31.5731,31.4806,31.349,31.3405,31.2251,31.0717,30.7287,30.6552,30.5264,30.3869,30.3099,30.2343,30.1371,30.0559]
l2 = [207.888,171.346,167.564,159.4,151.16,150,138.694,131.992,129.483,122.415,121.331,121.249,121.237,120.543,119.089,117.743,114.647,114.494,113.767,113.196,112.84,112.651,112.403,111.544,110.565,110.173,109.998,109.696,109.386,107.889,107.482,107.319,106.861,106.735,106.491,106.49,105.362,104.869,104.615,104.414,104.242,104.082,103.716,103.393,103.26,102.775,102.182,101.64,100.905,100.28,99.9022,99.884,99.3238,98.0795,97.7133,96.9512,96.9184,96.8695,96.7221,96.413,96.232,96.1422,95.8459,95.8459,95.8131,95.7728,95.3913,95.2376,94.8845,94.5705,93.2414,93.1552,92.5173,92.3415,92.2056,91.9852,91.9534,91.9501,91.9433,91.7053,91.49,91.3532,91.3028,91.1127,91.0899,90.8153,90.6707,90.4659,90.2175,90.2155,90.159,89.9459,89.5651,89.5639,89.1779,89.145,88.9312,88.8858,88.455,88.3704,88.2895,88.1412,87.9855,87.9778,87.9778,87.9013,87.6009,87.5154,87.1016,86.9321,86.7951,86.7836,86.7587,86.4046,86.1803,85.904,85.7661,85.7291,85.6081,85.5804,85.497,85.1705,85.0928,84.6087,84.4984,84.2268,83.8976,83.7881,83.7389,83.7389,83.5095,83.3326,83.0616,82.8301,82.794,82.794,82.7641,82.5966,82.4473,82.4219,82.2223,82.1793,82.0124,81.9174,81.8531,81.376,81.0667,81.0464,80.8922,80.8331,80.6349,80.5288,79.8589,79.8148,79.8148,79.6995,79.6146,79.6007,79.5844,79.4964,79.3517,79.298,79.1793,79.1632,79.0621,79.0124,78.9803,78.9774,78.8984,78.8976,78.8976,78.8805,78.8545,78.7977,78.7145,78.6846,78.6846,78.5711,78.4882,78.3885,78.1814,78.1159,78.0742,78.0108,77.9611,77.8295,77.8264,77.8001,77.5285,77.5232,77.2644,77.1439,77.1424,77.0046,76.9793,76.9487,76.8315,76.8283,76.8189,76.8189,76.7983,76.7027,76.7009,76.4747,76.4317,76.4124,76.3816,76.2862,76.1642,76.1527,75.9325,75.8247,75.7142,75.47,75.4662,75.4423,75.4232,75.333,75.0098,74.898,74.8773,74.8275,74.8053,74.7623,74.7514,74.6993,74.6993,74.6796,74.673,74.6625,74.2592,74.0637,74.0032,73.8717,73.6659,73.6505,73.5091,73.4831,73.4567,73.3633,73.2646,73.1528,72.9344,72.9313,72.8652,72.7537,72.5718,72.4492,72.4051,72.2192,72.1682,72.1634,72.0665,72.0289,71.6249,71.5958,71.5181,71.4805,71.3533,71.1772,71.1761,71.0991,71.053,71.0416,70.8338,70.488,70.4225,70.1584,70.1289,70.0825,70.0229,69.997,69.9822,69.9385,69.7941,69.723,69.5848,69.4934,69.4398,69.3906,69.3726,69.3726,69.2188,69.0563,68.8404,68.763,68.7606,68.7362,68.6994,68.657,68.6141,68.4659,68.3962,68.2867,68.2724,67.7605,67.6517,67.5337,67.5027,67.2305,67.2183,67.1789,67.0512,66.9404,66.69,66.6746,66.6483,66.6417,66.4847,66.4695,66.4503,66.4422,66.2737,66.0067,65.9082,65.8823,65.8823,65.8703,65.8449,65.7907,65.7635,65.7635,65.5651,65.5406,65.5047,65.4879,65.3959,65.2771,65.0997,65.0984,65.0023,64.7704,64.6576,64.6212,64.5761,64.482,64.3861,64.3453,64.2428,64.0602,64.0358,63.9648,63.94,63.8353,63.7891,63.7872,63.7437,63.7111,63.6128,63.5088,63.4259,63.3954,63.3381,63.2467,63.1638,63.1347,63.0981,63.0643,62.9795,62.9157,62.7673,62.7355,62.6865,62.6326,62.5611,62.3845,62.2136,62.1582,62.1221,62.0804,61.754,61.754,61.7538,61.5985,61.4088,61.392,61.2851,61.2619,61.2156,61.1782,61.1557,61.0956,61.0415,61.0297,60.9654,60.7681,60.6919,60.6803,60.5969,60.3806,60.3681,60.2862,60.2253,60.1682,60.1682,60.1452,60.1341,60.0051,59.9962,59.9775,59.9159,59.7761,59.6807,59.5799,59.5299,59.491,59.45,59.2914,59.1757,59.1162,58.9643,58.9336,58.916,58.9104,58.818,58.8159,58.6025,58.5532,58.5496,58.4647,58.2838,58.2579,58.1108,58.0855,58.0039,57.926,57.8545,57.8401,57.7977,57.4247,57.3585,57.3285,57.3285,57.2432,57.211,57.1942,57.1202,56.9691,56.8711,56.8627,56.8571,56.8326,56.7461,56.7351,56.7261,56.723,56.6504,56.6161,56.5315,56.4358,56.3995,56.3191,56.1791,56.1123,56.0066,55.9533,55.9467,55.9302,55.8873,55.7623,55.6959,55.5229,55.5216,55.4979,55.4929,55.4713,55.4565,55.4425,55.3594,55.3594,55.3583,55.3003,55.2434,55.0464,55.009,54.9714,54.9485,54.8953,54.8631,54.8077,54.8048,54.7574,54.6345,54.1857,54.0751,54.0189,53.948,53.712,53.6314,53.5875,53.5715,53.5661,53.5427,53.2477,53.077,53.0167,52.9753,52.8383,52.8235,52.8006,52.7509,52.7491,52.7464,52.5655,52.5612,52.5335,52.392,52.3605,52.2919,52.2889,52.2433,52.2337,51.9662,51.9639,51.9633,51.744,51.6756,51.6653,51.6248,51.6233,51.5476,51.5279,51.512,51.4396,51.3542,51.3091,51.1867,51.1765,51.1572,51.1562,50.9844,50.8947,50.8875,50.8654,50.7811,50.6834,50.6828,50.4879,50.3947,50.3924,50.3499,50.2686,50.2493,50.111,50.0893,50.0671,49.986,49.9593,49.9301,49.8905,49.872,49.7097,49.5889,49.5522,49.5216,49.5046,49.5,49.4539,49.444,49.2926,49.2884,49.2499,49.1404,49.1304,49.0876,49.0147,49.0147,48.9785,48.9616,48.8961,48.8185,48.5901,48.5854,48.5466,48.4818,48.459,48.4493,48.4289,48.2729,48.1958,48.1527,48.1499,48.14,48.0727,48.0451,47.999,47.9989,47.987,47.933,47.9187,47.8933,47.7601,47.7205,47.7088,47.7049,47.6592,47.627,47.5553,47.5182,47.4763,47.3752,47.2772,47.2718,47.2354,47.2021,47.1803,47.1628,47.1002,46.7306,46.7075,46.6655,46.6347,46.4787,46.4693,46.4693,46.4686,46.4304,46.4304,46.3982,46.3877,46.2395,46.2374,46.2374,46.1992,46.1781,46.1278,46.1276,46.1276,46.0755,45.8223,45.7552,45.7022,45.6475,45.4832,45.454,45.4023,45.1494,45.1494,45.0928,45.0437,45.0041,44.9834,44.8849]

data = {'control':l1, 'wt': l2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.melt().assign(x='')

order = ["control", "wt"]
boxpairs=[("control", "wt")]

a = sns.violinplot(data=df1, x="x", y="value", hue="variable",
               split=True, inner="quart", linewidth=2.5)

a1, test_results = add_stat_annotation(a, data=df1, x="variable", y="value", 
                                       order=order, box_pairs=boxpairs, 
                                       test='t-test_ind', text_format='star', 
                                       comparisons_correction=None, loc='outside',
                                       line_offset_to_box=0.2, line_offset=0.2, 
                                       line_height=0.05, text_offset=10, verbose=0)
```

I have tried to illustrate what I actually want in the output -

[image]

Does anyone know some workaround to move the annotation as shown above?

Comment: Any update on this? I have a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what you asked but you can do it manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l1 = [272.504,202.512,193.069,167.855,154.232,152.334,151.609,148.53,146.403,145.133,144.645,143.988,139.266,138.655,133.887,133.661,133.434,133.17,131.556,131.256,130.978,129.105,128.842,126.593,126.333,124.542,123.76,123.492,123.22,121.734,120.375,119.656,119.108,118.642,118.401,118.309,116.836,116.416,115.601,114.028,113.992,113.288,113.144,112.626,112.616,112.496,111.561,110.76,110.111,110.092,109.331,109.135,109.012,108.903,108.552,106.474,106.42,106.019,105.885,105.525,105.439,105.366,104.982,104.805,104.744,104.664,104.335,104.184,103.707,103.457,103.323,103.249,103.098,102.37,102.315,102.016,101.378,99.8643,99.5172,99.2789,99.2084,99.0091,97.7338,97.6874,97.6814,97.4388,96.432,96.2432,96.0918,96.0247,95.839,95.297,95.1323,94.2848,93.2593,93.2341,93.0388,92.3403,91.8436,91.8328,91.6193,91.3894,91.222,90.8495,90.734,90.7058,90.6775,90.5114,90.1493,90.0493,89.7854,89.6923,89.0814,89.0667,88.995,88.9301,88.7436,88.3927,88.3131,88.0119,87.4159,87.0414,86.9434,86.8593,86.7524,86.7398,86.2706,86.176,86.0691,85.9919,85.7879,85.6841,85.6708,85.3463,84.1721,84.066,83.7766,83.1467,83.0892,82.9535,82.816,82.5275,82.4752,82.471,82.4688,82.4646,81.9346,81.5371,81.3621,81.3368,80.9333,80.7021,80.6517,80.5567,80.1604,79.892,79.586,79.5603,79.4095,79.3454,79.2852,79.2086,79.0203,78.8051,78.706,78.6477,78.3607,78.0428,77.8758,77.5691,77.5387,77.5311,77.5263,77.3324,77.29,77.2234,77.0692,77.0666,77.0413,76.7028,76.5951,76.4135,76.392,76.3454,76.0672,75.6534,75.5475,75.2686,75.0235,74.9092,74.4248,74.2518,74.2257,74.0593,73.9968,73.9246,73.8414,73.8408,73.7763,73.4484,73.2291,73.145,73.0303,72.9797,72.9751,72.9024,72.826,72.6676,72.4249,72.4102,72.0856,71.9704,71.9172,71.7447,71.7206,71.5958,71.439,71.4298,71.2355,71.2251,71.0718,71.053,70.5732,70.4904,70.1866,69.8816,69.4722,69.4509,69.3045,69.2798,69.1982,69.1069,69.0067,68.6909,68.5816,68.4733,68.4249,68.024,68.0039,67.9734,67.7469,67.7361,67.713,67.6114,67.6018,67.4642,67.2782,67.0869,67.0519,66.8222,66.7673,66.6673,66.2306,66.1987,66.1889,66.0974,65.9233,65.8449,65.6032,65.3384,65.0957,65.0477,64.8658,64.7849,64.7369,64.7189,64.6764,64.6755,64.6455,64.4755,64.306,64.246,64.2147,64.0402,64.0325,63.8272,63.8245,63.6099,63.3386,63.2451,63.0935,63.0666,62.5662,62.4672,62.4578,62.4012,62.2842,62.2709,62.1582,61.9314,61.904,61.827,61.8042,61.7518,61.6945,61.6762,61.6359,61.5333,61.4807,61.304,61.1901,61.1656,61.1317,61.1297,60.9643,60.8862,60.6479,60.5511,60.5056,60.4721,60.4157,60.3676,60.1445,60.091,60.0761,60.0467,60.0336,59.9166,59.8809,59.8731,59.6334,59.5349,59.4131,59.3963,59.3804,59.361,59.3408,59.3174,59.2815,59.199,59.1076,58.8374,58.8146,58.8089,58.7414,58.5541,58.4368,58.2797,58.2499,58.1815,58.1174,58.1069,58.105,58.0428,57.9885,57.8912,57.8868,57.8822,57.676,57.6351,57.4839,57.4002,57.2343,57.1967,57.1731,57.0824,57.0567,56.8848,56.7218,56.4508,56.3671,56.3229,56.3205,56.1875,56.1257,56.0954,55.9887,55.8555,55.8546,55.809,55.7402,55.6578,55.5996,55.5602,55.5339,55.4469,55.3462,55.3444,55.3205,55.3117,55.2178,55.1261,55.0886,55.0576,54.9589,54.81,54.7532,54.7457,54.7033,54.5629,54.4999,54.3627,54.3135,54.311,54.2713,54.1049,54.0707,53.9745,53.77,53.5395,53.5006,53.3687,53.3117,53.2583,53.2529,53.2011,53.177,52.9779,52.909,52.905,52.6222,52.6088,52.5059,52.4902,52.4878,52.3373,52.3323,52.3029,52.3012,52.234,52.0334,51.9882,51.9661,51.9633,51.9121,51.8698,51.8114,51.788,51.6296,51.6248,51.4913,51.4739,51.3667,51.2958,51.294,51.2281,51.1854,51.1286,51.1162,51.0855,50.8662,50.5744,50.5062,50.4847,50.4691,50.4474,50.4179,50.2679,50.2074,50.1622,50.1334,49.7874,49.48,49.4539,49.4231,49.272,49.2575,49.1364,49.092,49.0221,48.8856,48.8175,48.7647,48.6915,48.647,48.6371,48.5609,48.5368,48.4042,48.234,48.1098,48.0656,47.9973,47.8853,47.7601,47.2543,47.2029,47.1206,47.1194,47.0535,46.9547,46.8645,46.8117,46.6366,46.3982,46.2792,46.2024,46.0142,45.8344,45.8233,45.8128,45.7977,45.7417,45.5822,45.5592,45.4089,45.3844,45.3696,45.136,45.0556,45.0016,45.0011,44.7754,44.6891,44.6553,44.6383,44.507,44.1616,44.1418,44.0245,43.9803,43.9753,43.968,43.8356,43.8177,43.6451,43.5594,43.3305,43.2629,43.2173,43.186,42.9444,42.8459,42.8095,42.7937,42.6379,42.5311,42.5082,42.4254,42.2728,42.1527,42.0969,42.0669,41.9709,41.9636,41.9144,41.9029,41.8869,41.8605,41.716,41.4758,41.4287,41.0717,41.0059,41.0017,40.9169,40.8871,40.7063,40.6942,40.6885,40.5788,40.5018,40.3402,40.3285,40.3031,40.2406,40.1971,40.167,40.1385,40.0427,39.8397,39.699,39.6931,39.6284,39.2814,39.2729,39.263,39.1405,39.1393,39.1139,39.0489,38.9667,38.8357,38.6099,38.4053,38.009,37.9577,37.8777,37.3667,37.1155,37.0287,36.9916,36.5744,36.2806,36.1317,36.0718,36.0612,36.039,35.9404,35.8914,35.8179,35.738,35.6264,35.5055,35.4206,35.4184,35.3975,35.3173,35.2659,35.1784,35.0709,34.8165,34.7544,34.7423,34.6369,34.6334,34.3476,34.3354,34.2578,34.1394,33.9828,33.9191,33.6455,33.6272,33.598,33.5212,33.3422,33.2855,33.2689,32.9122,32.8871,32.8818,32.4971,32.3061,32.2169,32.1022,31.9352,31.6088,31.5756,31.5731,31.4806,31.349,31.3405,31.2251,31.0717,30.7287,30.6552,30.5264,30.3869,30.3099,30.2343,30.1371,30.0559]
l2 = [207.888,171.346,167.564,159.4,151.16,150,138.694,131.992,129.483,122.415,121.331,121.249,121.237,120.543,119.089,117.743,114.647,114.494,113.767,113.196,112.84,112.651,112.403,111.544,110.565,110.173,109.998,109.696,109.386,107.889,107.482,107.319,106.861,106.735,106.491,106.49,105.362,104.869,104.615,104.414,104.242,104.082,103.716,103.393,103.26,102.775,102.182,101.64,100.905,100.28,99.9022,99.884,99.3238,98.0795,97.7133,96.9512,96.9184,96.8695,96.7221,96.413,96.232,96.1422,95.8459,95.8459,95.8131,95.7728,95.3913,95.2376,94.8845,94.5705,93.2414,93.1552,92.5173,92.3415,92.2056,91.9852,91.9534,91.9501,91.9433,91.7053,91.49,91.3532,91.3028,91.1127,91.0899,90.8153,90.6707,90.4659,90.2175,90.2155,90.159,89.9459,89.5651,89.5639,89.1779,89.145,88.9312,88.8858,88.455,88.3704,88.2895,88.1412,87.9855,87.9778,87.9778,87.9013,87.6009,87.5154,87.1016,86.9321,86.7951,86.7836,86.7587,86.4046,86.1803,85.904,85.7661,85.7291,85.6081,85.5804,85.497,85.1705,85.0928,84.6087,84.4984,84.2268,83.8976,83.7881,83.7389,83.7389,83.5095,83.3326,83.0616,82.8301,82.794,82.794,82.7641,82.5966,82.4473,82.4219,82.2223,82.1793,82.0124,81.9174,81.8531,81.376,81.0667,81.0464,80.8922,80.8331,80.6349,80.5288,79.8589,79.8148,79.8148,79.6995,79.6146,79.6007,79.5844,79.4964,79.3517,79.298,79.1793,79.1632,79.0621,79.0124,78.9803,78.9774,78.8984,78.8976,78.8976,78.8805,78.8545,78.7977,78.7145,78.6846,78.6846,78.5711,78.4882,78.3885,78.1814,78.1159,78.0742,78.0108,77.9611,77.8295,77.8264,77.8001,77.5285,77.5232,77.2644,77.1439,77.1424,77.0046,76.9793,76.9487,76.8315,76.8283,76.8189,76.8189,76.7983,76.7027,76.7009,76.4747,76.4317,76.4124,76.3816,76.2862,76.1642,76.1527,75.9325,75.8247,75.7142,75.47,75.4662,75.4423,75.4232,75.333,75.0098,74.898,74.8773,74.8275,74.8053,74.7623,74.7514,74.6993,74.6993,74.6796,74.673,74.6625,74.2592,74.0637,74.0032,73.8717,73.6659,73.6505,73.5091,73.4831,73.4567,73.3633,73.2646,73.1528,72.9344,72.9313,72.8652,72.7537,72.5718,72.4492,72.4051,72.2192,72.1682,72.1634,72.0665,72.0289,71.6249,71.5958,71.5181,71.4805,71.3533,71.1772,71.1761,71.0991,71.053,71.0416,70.8338,70.488,70.4225,70.1584,70.1289,70.0825,70.0229,69.997,69.9822,69.9385,69.7941,69.723,69.5848,69.4934,69.4398,69.3906,69.3726,69.3726,69.2188,69.0563,68.8404,68.763,68.7606,68.7362,68.6994,68.657,68.6141,68.4659,68.3962,68.2867,68.2724,67.7605,67.6517,67.5337,67.5027,67.2305,67.2183,67.1789,67.0512,66.9404,66.69,66.6746,66.6483,66.6417,66.4847,66.4695,66.4503,66.4422,66.2737,66.0067,65.9082,65.8823,65.8823,65.8703,65.8449,65.7907,65.7635,65.7635,65.5651,65.5406,65.5047,65.4879,65.3959,65.2771,65.0997,65.0984,65.0023,64.7704,64.6576,64.6212,64.5761,64.482,64.3861,64.3453,64.2428,64.0602,64.0358,63.9648,63.94,63.8353,63.7891,63.7872,63.7437,63.7111,63.6128,63.5088,63.4259,63.3954,63.3381,63.2467,63.1638,63.1347,63.0981,63.0643,62.9795,62.9157,62.7673,62.7355,62.6865,62.6326,62.5611,62.3845,62.2136,62.1582,62.1221,62.0804,61.754,61.754,61.7538,61.5985,61.4088,61.392,61.2851,61.2619,61.2156,61.1782,61.1557,61.0956,61.0415,61.0297,60.9654,60.7681,60.6919,60.6803,60.5969,60.3806,60.3681,60.2862,60.2253,60.1682,60.1682,60.1452,60.1341,60.0051,59.9962,59.9775,59.9159,59.7761,59.6807,59.5799,59.5299,59.491,59.45,59.2914,59.1757,59.1162,58.9643,58.9336,58.916,58.9104,58.818,58.8159,58.6025,58.5532,58.5496,58.4647,58.2838,58.2579,58.1108,58.0855,58.0039,57.926,57.8545,57.8401,57.7977,57.4247,57.3585,57.3285,57.3285,57.2432,57.211,57.1942,57.1202,56.9691,56.8711,56.8627,56.8571,56.8326,56.7461,56.7351,56.7261,56.723,56.6504,56.6161,56.5315,56.4358,56.3995,56.3191,56.1791,56.1123,56.0066,55.9533,55.9467,55.9302,55.8873,55.7623,55.6959,55.5229,55.5216,55.4979,55.4929,55.4713,55.4565,55.4425,55.3594,55.3594,55.3583,55.3003,55.2434,55.0464,55.009,54.9714,54.9485,54.8953,54.8631,54.8077,54.8048,54.7574,54.6345,54.1857,54.0751,54.0189,53.948,53.712,53.6314,53.5875,53.5715,53.5661,53.5427,53.2477,53.077,53.0167,52.9753,52.8383,52.8235,52.8006,52.7509,52.7491,52.7464,52.5655,52.5612,52.5335,52.392,52.3605,52.2919,52.2889,52.2433,52.2337,51.9662,51.9639,51.9633,51.744,51.6756,51.6653,51.6248,51.6233,51.5476,51.5279,51.512,51.4396,51.3542,51.3091,51.1867,51.1765,51.1572,51.1562,50.9844,50.8947,50.8875,50.8654,50.7811,50.6834,50.6828,50.4879,50.3947,50.3924,50.3499,50.2686,50.2493,50.111,50.0893,50.0671,49.986,49.9593,49.9301,49.8905,49.872,49.7097,49.5889,49.5522,49.5216,49.5046,49.5,49.4539,49.444,49.2926,49.2884,49.2499,49.1404,49.1304,49.0876,49.0147,49.0147,48.9785,48.9616,48.8961,48.8185,48.5901,48.5854,48.5466,48.4818,48.459,48.4493,48.4289,48.2729,48.1958,48.1527,48.1499,48.14,48.0727,48.0451,47.999,47.9989,47.987,47.933,47.9187,47.8933,47.7601,47.7205,47.7088,47.7049,47.6592,47.627,47.5553,47.5182,47.4763,47.3752,47.2772,47.2718,47.2354,47.2021,47.1803,47.1628,47.1002,46.7306,46.7075,46.6655,46.6347,46.4787,46.4693,46.4693,46.4686,46.4304,46.4304,46.3982,46.3877,46.2395,46.2374,46.2374,46.1992,46.1781,46.1278,46.1276,46.1276,46.0755,45.8223,45.7552,45.7022,45.6475,45.4832,45.454,45.4023,45.1494,45.1494,45.0928,45.0437,45.0041,44.9834,44.8849]

data = {'control':l1, 'wt': l2}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.melt().assign(x='')

order = ["control", "wt"]
boxpairs=[("control", "wt")]

a = sns.violinplot(data=df1, x="x", y="value", hue="variable",
               split=True, inner="quart", linewidth=2.5)

#Mann-Whitney U-Test
import scipy.stats as stats
# perform two-sided test.
mwu = stats.mannwhitneyu(x=df1[df1['variable']=='control']['value'], 
                         y=df1[df1['variable']=='wt']['value'],
                         alternative = 'two-sided')
p_val = mwu[1]

# add MWUT annotations
# test 1
x1, x2 = -0.05, 0.05   
y, h, col = df1['value'].max()+30, 5, 'k'
plt.plot([x1, x1, x2, x2], [y, y+h, y+h, y], lw=1.5, c=col)
plt.text((x1+x2)*.5, y+h, f"* - {p_val}", ha='center', va='bottom', color=col)

a.set(ylim=(df1['value'].min()-60, df1['value'].max()+60))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227473/how-to-set-the-range-of-y-axis-for-a-seaborn-boxplot)

Answer (score 0):

To get the annotation for the split of one violin you can define the boxpairs like this

```
boxpairs_hue = [
    (("X", "control"), ("X", "wt")),
    (("Y", "control"), ("Y", "wt"))
]
```

If you then set a hue parameter in the `add_stat_annotation` function, you get the statistics for each hue split.

```
a1, test_results_migrations = add_stat_annotation(a, data=df1, x="variable", y="value", hue="variable", box_pairs=boxpairs_hue, test='t-test_ind', text_format='star',comparisons_correction=None, loc='outside',line_offset_to_box=0.2, line_offset=0.2, line_height=0.05, text_offset=10, verbose=0)
```

Example from the [statannot Notebook](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot/blob/master/example/example.ipynb):

> ````
> x: x in 'EIJ')]
>
> # Modifying data to yield unequal boxes in the hue value df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Ideal', 'price'] = df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Ideal',
> 'price'].map(lambda x: min(x, 5000)) df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Premium',
> 'price'] = df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Premium', 'price'].map(lambda x:
> min(x, 7500)) df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Good', 'price'] = df.loc[df['cut']
> == 'Good', 'price'].map(lambda x: min(x, 15000)) df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Very Good', 'price'] = df.loc[df['cut'] == 'Very Good',
> 'price'].map(lambda x: min(x, 3000))
>
> x = "color" y = "price" hue = "cut" hue_order=['Ideal', 'Premium',
> 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Fair'] box_pairs=[
>     (("E", "Ideal"), ("E", "Very Good")),
>     (("E", "Ideal"), ("E", "Premium")),
>     (("E", "Ideal"), ("E", "Good")),
>     (("I", "Ideal"), ("I", "Premium")),
>     (("I", "Ideal"), ("I", "Good")),
>     (("J", "Ideal"), ("J", "Premium")),
>     (("J", "Ideal"), ("J", "Good")),
>     (("E", "Good"), ("I", "Ideal")),
>     (("I", "Premium"), ("J", "Ideal")),
>     ] ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue,) add_stat_annotation(ax, data=df, x=x, y=y, hue=hue,
> box_pairs=box_pairs,
>                     test='Mann-Whitney', loc='inside', verbose=2) plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.03, 1)) ```
> ````